# Query working in psql, but not working with pg.js

Tags: postgresql, express, pg

I have a query that works in `psql`, but when I insert it into my REST service it doesnt work.  Here is my code:

```
exports.getProjects = function(req, res) {
  'use strict';
  var query = client.query('select projects.project_id, array_to_string(array_agg(distinct project_subservices.subservice_id), ',') as subservices, array_to_string(array_agg(distinct project_certifications.certification_id), ',') as certifications from projects left outer join project_subservices on projects.project_id = project_subservices.project_id left outer join  project_certifications on projects.project_id = project_certifications.project_id group by projects.project_id');
  query.on('row', function(row, result) {
    result.addRow(row);
  });
  query.on('end', function(result) {
    var finalResult = {};
    finalResult.meta = {};
    finalResult.meta.count = result.rows.length;
    finalResult.projects = result.rows;
    res.json(finalResult);
  });
};
```

Here is the error I get:

```
/home/jason/Projects/Node/isx_server/node_modules/pg/lib/native/index.js:141
    this._sendQueryWithParams(query.text, query.values, query.singleRowMode);
         ^
Error: Values must be an array
    at Connection._pulseQueryQueue (/home/jason/Projects/Node/isx_server/node_modules/pg/lib/native/index.js:141:10)
    at Connection.connection.on.clientBuilder.port (/home/jason/Projects/Node/isx_server/node_modules/pg/lib/native/index.js:241:18)
    at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:93:17)
```

I can cut and paste this code into `psql` and it works find.  What is the difference in the 2 environments that will cause the query not to work?  How do I make this work?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please show us your code! But anyway, your problem seems to be that you pass to `sendQueryWithParams` an argument (`query.value`), that it expects it to be an array, but it's not.

Comment: I added the full code.

Answer (score 1):

You're not escaping those single quotes, so your js function things you're passing three variables instead of a single one…

If memory serves, js allows to use double quotes as string delimiters, so use that instead of single quotes seeing that you're not using double quotes in the query.

Else, add backslashes where needed to escape the single quotes.